# SQL QUERY change column name after convert of date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, listview

```
SELECT 
  m.MapID, convert(nvarchar, m.CreateDate, 103)

returns 
MapId (No Column name)
102   13/03/17
103   13/03/17
104   14/03/17
```

because I am removing the time from dateTime m.CreateDate it is returning the column name as (No Column Name), but I need to change this to 'DateCreated' as that is what my listview is looking for when I am binding in code behind

Comment: `convert(nvarchar, m.CreateDate, 103) as DateCreated`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an alias on the column.

```
 SELECT m.MapID, convert(nvarchar, m.CreateDate, 103) as CreateDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.  First, *never* use `nvarchar` (or related types) without a string length.  The default length varies by context.  So, this is a bug waiting to happen.

Second, you simply need `as` to give a table alias:

```
SELECT m.MapID, convert(nvarchar(255), m.CreateDate, 103) as CreateDate
```

(255 is an arbitrary number that is morethan big enough for this purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  m.MapID, 
  convert(nvarchar, m.CreateDate, 103) As 'DateCreated'
```

Will do it.

thanks